# Editing .sol-files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am looking for a way to edit .sol-files (LSO/Local Shared Object). I have tried searching quite a bit, but I have not been able to find any program that can edit AS3-files properly. Is there a solution for me out there?

Comment: You say "I have not been able to find any program that can edit AS3-files properly". You should be able to edit .as ActionScript files with any text editor. Not .sol files though. Perhaps you meant to say .sol files there too.

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript Viewer includes SOL Viewer and Editor which can view/edit these files.

http://www.buraks.com/asv/tools/sve.html

> ASV SOL Viewer and Editor adds 'View and Edit SOL Files' option to ASV.
>
> SOL (Local Shared Object) files are created by SWF files to store persistent data on the user's computer, similar to a cookie.
>
> With ASV SOL Viewer and Editor you can,
>
> - Open and view SOL files,
> - Edit contents of SOL files,
> - Create new SOL files.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use [Sol Editor](http://www.alexisisaac.net/flash/articles/.sol-editor-local-shared-object--2.html), but I have run into a few .sol files that it won't read.

[Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) has(?) a .sol reader, but not an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Minerva is the most awesome sol reader and editor, but unfortunately you cant add new elements. You can just edit them.

Comment: It's got some advertising on it doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FlashDevelop, look under Tools > FlashTools > SharedObject Reader... Works for all AMF versions, unlike most of the other SOL inspectors you can find by Googling, that are pretty dated.

Answer (score 0):

I was found this online editor - https://mariani.life/projects/minerva/
This works for me fine. You can upload, edit and download edited file, for me it very convenient.